# Async calls in $q.all?

Tags: asynchronous, ng-grid

I have a following case.
A ngGrid which labels are read from asynchronous Service so labels are read dynamically and tey are not hard coded.

I have gathered all asynchronous calls fetching label data into $q.all and then fetching their data in the .then part.

But in some cases labels are not shown into ngGrid so this must be something to do with asynchronous calls and ngGrid synchronizing.

How should I code $q.all and it async calls so that I would be sure that when they are set into ngGrid they contain proper labels?

Br Dan

```
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    myService.getAttribute(key, function(label) {
      var result = label;
      deferred.resolve(result);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  };

  /** Fetching labels asynchronously */
  $q.all(
      [   getLabelTxt('Form.Field1'),
          getLabelTxt('Form.Field2'),
          getLabelTxt('Form.Field3') ]).then(
      function(data) {
        $scope.setColDefs(data);
      });

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data : 'dataModel',
    enableColumnResize : true,
    selectedItems : [],
    columnDefs : [
                  {
                    field : 'Field1',
                    displayName : ''
                  }, {
                    field : 'Field2',
                    displayName : ''
                  }, {
                    field : 'Field3',
                    displayName : ''                          
                  } ]
  };

  /** Setting values fetched from Asynch service */
  $scope.setColDefs = function(rows) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[i] !== undefined) {
        $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[i].displayName = rows[i];
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-grid 2.x puts a `$watch` on the columnDefs if it is a string. Otherwise it won't do any updates. You can define your columnDefs like so:

```js
$scope.columns = [
  { field : 'Field1' },
  { field : 'Field2' },
  { field : 'Field3' }
];

$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = 'columns';
```

And then update `$scope.columns` directly:

```js
$scope.setColDefs = function(rows) {
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.columns[i] !== undefined) {
      $scope.columns[i].displayName = rows[i];
    }
  }
};
```

Here's an example plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fc6QVp?p=preview